# Relationships between tables without foreign key in database in heidisql

Tags: heidisql

I am looking at one database, which somebody else created, and I am trying to find relationship between tables. But those tables have only keys (indexes), and some of them have primary key too.  There is not a single foreign key.
I would like to figure out how these tables are connected to each other, but I do not know how to do It here ? 
I would like to request as simple as possible explanation, as I am not very good in this area.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: If you are lucky the column names could give you some hints. Otherwise you have to look at the data in the database or at the code of the application that uses this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no foreign keys defined, there is no link between tables.
You'll have to find out the relationships via the table and column names.

Because foreign key constraints are not being enforced right now, there is a chance that adding them is not possible if the data is not consistent.

Adding foreign keys with HeidiSQL is simple and fast. Also, when you have edit a foreign key value in a data grid, HeidiSQL shows a dropdown with the first text field that it finds in the linked table. Nice feature.

Comment: first two sentences together are confusing me a bit :) if there is no link between tables, how come there is relationship than ? 
I am very grateful for your help. just trying to understand: So, if there is possibility for relationship between tables I will have to search It by column names (have to be same in different tables?). And If I search for cardinality (1:1, 1:N etc) between tables, maybe I can do that by quering between tables ?

Comment: I understand now when I have read your answer few times more :) If you would like to add any additional suggestion on this would be also great, but anyway I got the point

Comment: @activepower123: when you see a column called `personid`, there's a good change that it's actually should have a foreign key to the `id` column in the table `person`.
Also remember, when you want to add a foreign key, the fields in both tables need to have an index, and need to be of the same type.